# randomize Nested symbols for coin blocks

Tags: actionscript-3, random, flash-cs6

I have a MovieClip object called **coinblock1**.

**Problem:**
Coinblock1 has 6 frames and I want to choose a random frame **number** from this MC object. 
I want to use this number to later update some other variables by using an `IF` statement.
Variables to update include the changing of amount of coins earned by the player.

My frame numbers are arranged like this:

```
frame 1 = 0 coins
frame 2 = 1 coins 
frame 3 = 5 coins
frame 4 = 10 coins
frame 5 = 50 coins
frame 6 = 100 coins
```

How to randomize the range for following frames in the coin block? 
I have used the `if...else` statement and `gotoAndStop` in a `currentFrame`.

**My Code:**

```
if(coinblock1.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true)
{
    if (ballSpeedXCoinGame > 0) 
    {
        ballSpeedXCoinGame *= -1;
        ballSpeedYCoinGame = calculateBallAngleCoinGame(character.y, blowfishPong.y);
        var random1: uint = 0;
        random1 = Math.random() * coinblock1.totalFrames;       
        if (random == 1){
                coinblock1.gotoAndStop(1);
                Bump.play();
            }
            else{
                if(random == 2){
                    Coins += 1;
                    coinblock1.gotoAndStop(2);
                }
                if(random == 3){
                    Coins += 5;
                    coinblock1.gotoAndStop(3);
                }
                if(random == 4){
                    Coins += 10;
                    coinblock1.gotoAndStop(4);
                }
                if(random == 5){
                    Coins += 50;
                    coinblock1.gotoAndStop(5);
                    }
                if(random == 6){
                    Coins += 100;
                    coinblock1.gotoAndStop(6);
                    }
                updateTextFieldsCoinGame();
                CoinSFX.play();
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You use **randomCoin** as a numeric variable first, but then you act as if it is a **MovieClip**. So, if you indeed have a **randomCoin** as a **MovieClip** there, you should rename the local variable to something else.

Comment: How to do make randomCoin as a numeric variable as a MovieClip?

Comment: Sorry, what you are asking makes no sense. A numeric variable holds a value like **int**, **uint** or **Number**, and it is not a **MovieClip**. A **MovieClip** variable is not numeric, it contains a reference to a **MovieClip** object. If your **randomCoin** is an actual **MovieClip** (designed on timeline, with the instance name of **randomCoin**), you should leave it as is, and make another variable to define a random frame: **var aFrame:int = Math.random() * coinblock.length + 1;**

Comment: The script is changed. Then, Randomize the frame than 0? Is it Math.random() * coinblock.length + 1?

Comment: So, what is the problem now? Did the error go away?

Comment: No errors. I need to randomize the nested symbols to random the number of frames.  
E.g. coinblock1 is a MovieClip. There are 6 frames inside the nested symbol.

Comment: Ah! The **MovieClip** class doesn't have a **length** property, you should put it as the following: **random1 = Math.random() * coinblock1.totalFrames + 1;** You don't need to **Math.floor(...)** it because the variable is **uint** and the result is auto-converted.

Comment: Ok. What the ".currentFrame" for the random?

Comment: Not sure what are you asking. The rest of script is *logically* correct. You tell a **MovieClip** to **gotoAndPlay(...)** and that changes its **currentFrame**.

Comment: Ok. So, what about this? coinblock1.gotoAndStop(random1);
    if(coinblock1.currentFrame == 2){
     Coins += 1;
     CoinSFX.play();
    }
    else if(coinblock1.currentFrame == 3){
     Coins += 5;
     CoinSFX.play();
    }
    else if(coinblock1.currentFrame == 4){
     Coins += 10;
     CoinSFX.play();
    }
    else if(coinblock1.currentFrame == 5){
     Coins += 50;
     CoinSFX.play();
    }
    else if(coinblock1.currentFrame == 6){
     Coins += 100;
     CoinSFX.play();
    }
    else if (coinblock1.currentFrame == 1){
     Bump.play();
    }

Comment: @IsaacYeapJieLing It doesn't make sense to ask _"what about this?"_... You did not say what you want to know, so what answer do you expect here? Test the code and if there's any problems, then [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74913206/edithttps://stackoverflow.com/posts/74913206/edit) with the new code and new error so we can try to see a possible solution.

Comment: @IsaacYeapJieLing _"What the `.currentFrame` for the random?"_  Are you asking what number is **random1**? If yes, use `trace ( "random1 is : " + random1);` then you can know which frame number the `coinblock1.gotoAndStop( random1 );` is going to... Where it stops is the new `coinblock1.currentFrame` (frame number is same number as **Random1**)...

Comment: Yes. Each frame in a coin block nested symbol is 0, 1, 5, 10, 50 and 100 coins to randomize it in a current frame.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is you want to get a random number and then use it in an IF statement to control which frame the **coinblock1** goes to and also to update the  **coins** amount.

For that, try something like this logic below:

```
if(coinblock1.hitTestObject(blowfishPong) == true)
{
    if (ballSpeedXCoinGame > 0) 
    {
        ballSpeedXCoinGame *= -1;
        ballSpeedYCoinGame = calculateBallAngleCoinGame(character.y, blowfishPong.y);
        
        //# ::: Step 1 ::: first you define a variable (it has value of zero)
        var random1: uint = 0;
        
        //# then you update the variable (with some random value)
        random1 = ( Math.random() * coinblock1.totalFrames ); 
        
        //# finally you check what the new updated value is now
        trace( "random1 is : " + random1 );
        
        //# ::: Step 2 ::: update coins amount and then change coinblock's frame number
       
        if( random1 == 1 ) //# will do this part if random1 is 1..
        {
            coinblock1.gotoAndStop(1);
            Bump.play();
        }
        
        else //# will do this part if random1 is NOT 1..
        {
            if( random1 == 2 )
            {
                Coins += 1;
                coinblock1.gotoAndStop(2);  
            }

            if( random1 == 3 )
            {
                Coins += 5;
                coinblock1.gotoAndStop(3);
            }

            if( random1 == 4 )
            {
                Coins += 10;
                coinblock1.gotoAndStop(4);
            }

            if( random1 == 5 )
            {
                Coins += 50;
                coinblock1.gotoAndStop(5);
            }

            if( random1 == 6 )
            {
                Coins += 100;
                coinblock1.gotoAndStop(6);  
            }
            
            //# after the IF's... now update the in-game text and also play a sound
            updateTextFieldsCoinGame();
            CoinSFX.play();
        
        } //# end of ELSE part

    }
}
```

Comment: PS: I cannot test AS3 code so tell me if my code example is doing what you needed...

Comment: I have tested. but the coin block makes different sounds: 1. get a coin with a bump sound and no coins added. 2. hit a block no coins with a coin sound.

Comment: _"I have tested. but the coin block makes different sounds:"_ Yes that is what your code does. You can see you have `CoinSFX.play();` and `Bump.play()` for different sounds...  I don't understand your point **1.**, how can it be **get a coin** but at same time is also **no coins added**? I cannot explain your point **2.** (`hit a block no coins with a coin sound`). You have `Coins +=` so the code should be adding coins. What is _"hit a block no coins"_ meaning? I ask again **tell me if my code example is doing what you needed.**. If not correct, then you must also tell **what should happen**.

Comment: One of the coin blocks have hit and reached Frame 1 in a nested symbol but it makes a coin sound instead of a bump sound

Comment: OK I now understand better what you are meaning. So the problem is: You touch `coinblock1`, and then the trace says `"random1 is : 1"`, and then you see `coinblock1` going to frame 1, but the problem now is that the Sound is `CoinSFX.play();` instead of being `Bump.play()`? .. Things you can try to fix: **(1)** Make sure there is no code on Frame 1 of `coinblock1` to play other Sound. **(2)** Check in Library that your Bump and CoinSFX are using correct sound files. Maybe you got wrong Var names to the Sounds (like saying `Bump = coin_sound.mp3` so later your `bump.play()` gives a coin sound?)

Comment: var CoinSFX: Coin = new Coin(); var Bump: brickbump = new brickbump(); They are already matched the correct sounds and they are in a library.

Comment: Okay... **(1)** I don't know what is `new Coin` in your `var CoinSFX: Coin = new Coin();` I mean is that a Sound (MP3) object? or maybe it is a MovieClip object with frames?... Also I don't understand about the command `CoinSFX.play` is that one telling a **Sound** to play or is that one telling a **MovieClip** to play?  **(2)** Your question is about **Randomize Nested symbols for coin block** and that is what **must be fixed first**.  If  **random frame** is working then this question is Answered correctly. If there is a new problem about sound then ask a new question about Sound.